# Postgres database running in docker keeps hanging

Tags: postgresql, docker

I'm using the postgres docker image, and after months of using databases running in docker images, now I'm getting the behaviour where after a certain period of time, they simply just hang. I can exec with `bin/bash` but can't do anything with postgres at all; the commands don't return and the containers can't be brought down. Even `docker kill -s SIGKILL <container_id>` doesn't work; needs a reboot of the docker server to stop them.

The only smoking gun I can see is the message:

```
 WARNING:  could not open statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/global.stat": Operation not permitted
```

on all containers. Anyone has any ideas I'd be really appreciative as this is killing things at the moment.

Comment: Who is using postgres (I guess you have some kind of backend connecting to it...). What kind of data do you handle. Do you have any large or complex queries that might render postgres without memory or the server without space?

Comment: This is actually on my laptop. No large or complex queries. Not much data. There's plenty of memory left.

Comment: I'm having the same issue on my dev environment since upgrading to the latest version of docker

Comment: I've downgraded docker from 2.5 to 2.4 and so far it's going better..

Comment: This is very interesting - I actually went through a process of moving the pg_stat dir which didn't help and didn't fail on 2.5, but after dropping to 2.4 it caused failures. Fortunately I had just renamed it so restored that pg_stat dir and it was fine in 2.4. There's something peculiar about 2.5...

Comment: FWIW I get these same WARNINGs frequently in my Postgres logs on docker, but it doesn't seem to cause any hangs in my case. PostgreSQL 9.6.15, docker engine 19.03.13, macOS High Sierra.

Answer (score 13):

This is happening due to a user permission mismatch in the docker container.

Listing the relevant files in the container:

```
$ docker exec <container> ls -l /var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_stat_tmp
-rw------- 1 root     root     [...] db_0.stat
-rw------- 1 root     root     [...] db_1.stat
-rw------- 1 root     root     [...] db_2.stat
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres [...] global.stat
```

we can see that all the `db_*.stat` files are owned by `root:root`, while `global.stat` is owned by `postgres:postgres`.

Checking the docker user gives us:

```
$ docker exec <container> whoami
root
```

So, we'd like all of these files to be owned by the postgres user.
Luckily, this is quite easy! Just set user to `postgres`, and restart!

In a dockerfile:

```
USER postgres
```

Using docker-compose:

```
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:13
    user: postgres
```

Comment: Not working for me. All files or dirs under Postgres data directory are belong to `postgres:postgres`, but the logs by `docker logs -f postgres` still pop 
```
WARNING:  could not open statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/global.stat": Operation not permitted
```

Answer (score 0):

As Norling and Dharman's answer did not work for me, I've tried another way: leaving the temporary file in container - and that worked. I've changed with inline command the Postgresql config:

```
postgresdb: 
    image: 'postgres'
    command: postgres -c stats_temp_directory=/tmp
    .
    .
    .
```